# CSS wont effect a className of an object created in a loop

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am currently trying to have 10 horizontal lines that I have created be styled with CSS. They appear on the screen but I can't seem to have CSS affect them. The class name I have given them is "horizontal".

REACT.JS CODE

```
import React from "react";
import "./home.css";
import myPicture from "../../assets/picofme.png";

const HorizontalLines = ({ numberOfLines }) => {
  const lines = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
    lines.push(<hr key={i} className="horizontal" />);
  }

  return <div>{lines}</div>;
};

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <section id="home">
      <div className="homeContent">
        <span className="hi">Hello,</span>
        <span className="intro">
          I'm <span className="Me">Me</span>
          <br />
          software
        </span>
        <p className="introPara">
         This is my experince
          developer.{" "}
          <p>Here are my solutions</p>
        </p>
      </div>
      <img src={myPicture} alt="profile" className="myPicture" />
      <HorizontalLines numberOfLines={10} />
    </section>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

MY CSS CODE

```
#home {
  height: calc(100vh - 4rem);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 98%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.horizontal {
  z-index: -4;
  color: #22c8ff;
}
```

All the other classNames are being used in the CSS code but I am unable to show them.

Comment: [Works for me](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/stupefied-shannon-f2p788?file=%2Fsrc%2FHome.js%3A29%2C17).  (Though it's worth noting that neither of the CSS rules used in that class have any visible effect anyway.)  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, or clarify specifically how you are observing the problem?

Comment: @David Right now I have the 10 horizontal lines appear in front of the rest of my page. Though when I try to access the className = "horizontal" the color is still white and not changing to the blue. Also when I try to position and margin the lines those wont go through either.

Comment: *"the color is still white and not changing to the blue"* - You've changed the text color to blue, but `<hr>` elements have no text.  Did you mean to set `border-color`?

Comment: @David Thank you for mentioning that. Though I don't understand why the z-index wont work in having the<hr> go behind an <img>

Comment: If you're not already examining the resulting DOM in your browser's debugging tools, I recommend familiarizing yourself with that.  In mine the `z-index` style rule is disabled with the message: *"The position: static property prevents z-index from having an effect. Try setting position to something other than static."*

Comment: @David Got it, I will do that Thank you for everything!